# Creating Properly-Nested XML Output in Python

Tags: python, xml, output

I'm attempting to save data from several lists in XML format, but I cannot understand how to make the XML display properly. An example of my code right now is as follows:

```
from lxml import etree

#Create XML Root
articles = etree.Element('root')

#Create Lists & Data
t_list = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4', 'title5']
c_list = ['content1', 'content2', 'content3', 'content4', 'content5']
sum_list = ['summary1', 'summary2', 'summary3', 'summary4', 'summary5']
s_list = ['source1', 'source2', 'source3', 'source4', 'source5']

i = 0
for t in t_list:
    for i in range(len(t_list)):
        #Create SubElements of XML Root
        article = etree.SubElement(articles, 'Article')
        titles = etree.SubElement(article, 'Title')
        summary = etree.SubElement(article, 'Summary')
        source = etree.SubElement(article, 'Source')
        content = etree.SubElement(article, 'Content')

        #Add List Data to SubElements
        titles.text = t_list[i]
        summary.text = sum_list[i]
        source.text = s_list[i]
        content.text = c_list[i]

print(etree.tostring(articles, pretty_print=True))
```

My Current Output is written in one very jumbled fashion, all on a single line as follows:

```
b'<root>\n  <Article>\n    <Title>title1</Title>\n    <Summary>summary1</Summary>\n    <Source>source1</Source>\n    <Content>content1</Content>\n  </Article>\n
```

It looks like the `pretty_print` function within `lxml` is adding proper indentation, as well as `\n` breaks as I would want, but it doesn't seem to be getting interpreted correctly during output; it write on a single line.

The output I'm trying to get is as follows:

```
<root>
  <Article>
    <Title>title1</Title>
    <Summary>summary1</Summary>
    <Source>source1</Source>
    <Content>content1</Content>
  </Article>
```

Ideally, I'd like for my output to be viewed as a valid XML document, and display in proper nested format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Current Output" is the *representation* (internal python representation) of the bytestring generated by `etree.tostring()`, and seems that in Python3 `print(somebytestring)` prints the representation instead of the actual string.

Hopefully the solution is quite simple: just pass the [desired encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) to `etree.tostring()`, ie:

```
xml = etree.tostring(articles, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True) 
print(xml)
```

Comment: the `encoding="unicode"` did  exactly what I was wanting

Answer (score 0):

I've only used the base ET module in Python and can't find an lxml download for python 3.5 (which I'm on) in order to test it, but the *b* before the line indicates bytes and a quick glance at the documentation indicates that tostring() has an encoding keyword, so you should just need to set that to unicode or utf-8.

I'll also mention that you don't need to set "i" before your for-loop (python will create the "i" it needs for the for-loop), though I- personally- would *zip* the lists and iterate the items in the lists themselves (though that's not going to have any real impact on the code in this situation).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Python and regardless of impact on output, I appreciate the advice.